# Efficiency when rearranging arrays in OpenGL

Tags: c++, performance, opengl

Imagine I have a vertex array and an index array. Suppose it is possible to rearrange the elements in the index array so that a single call `glDrawElements` with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` draws the desired figure. Another possibility would be to call `glDrawElements` with `GL_TRIANGLES` but this would make the index array longer.

Does it really matter in terms of efficiency (I mean real efficiency, not some microoptimizations) which way I choose or is the underlying routine the same anyway?

A side note: The reason I am reluctant to rearrange my elements to use `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` is that because I think that the triangles in the strip will have alternating winding. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no really performance differences between a call with `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` and `GL_TRIANGLES`.

Now if you can rearrange your indices for maximizing post-transform vertex cache, you can have huge performance gains. I did so years ago for rendering large terrain patches and observed 10 to 15 times FPS speedups (using some kind of Hilbert curve scheme).

Comment: -1: Triangle strips handle winding just fine. Since each alternating triangle has the opposite winding, OpenGL (and D3D for that matter) will simply reverse the winding test for every other triangle. So you don't need to do anything special.

Comment: Sure, triangle strips handle winding fine (else back face culling wouldn't work). What I wanted to say (I admit it's not clear in my answer) is that it's best to draw a mesh with one triangle list draw call (and not multiple triangle strip ones). If you want to draw multiple strips in one single call, you'll need degenerated triangles between them, or better use the special index for restarting strip (if you have the extension).

Answer (score 4):

I think that `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` and `GL_TRIANGLES` are quite as efficient, if your indices are ordered in a way to maximize vertex transform cache. Of course it will take more memory to store.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what's a vertex transform cache and how to maximize it?

Comment: The average distance between two indices in your element array. This way, OpenGL can use already transformed vertex when drawing a new triangle.

Comment: That's the pre-transform cache, it sounds like. (Though the element array is always accessed linearly, so distance is irrelevant.) The post-transform cache is a mapping from input index to vertex shader result, and it doesn't care about the actual values. For best results, you need to take both into account. For an algorithm, see http://home.comcast.net/~tom_forsyth/papers/fast_vert_cache_opt.html - it mainly deals with the post-transform cache, but the end section points out that pre-transform cache optimisation is just as important. Memory is really slow compared to the GPU.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably not much of a performance difference. But it's still recommended that you not use either method in the main render loop. Instead use display lists. I've converted some of my OpenGL code to display lists, and it's way faster because you end up cutting out a ton of CPU->GPU communication.

There's a tutorial here: http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/displaylists/

Comment: Yeah, use display lists, this way you can perfectly optimize your `glBegin/glEnd` calls. Sorry, but even 2010 display lists and begin/end have been way deprecated. Use `glDrawArrays/Elements` with VBOs. Simply put, if you don't have heavy CPU-GPU commumication there's no need to cut it down.

Comment: Well I suppose it depends on your target...VBOs are only supported in more modern versions of OpenGL. Depending on the application, that may or may not be an issue. Use the right tool for the job.

Comment: But that's definitely not what you answer suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on what your driver has to do with your vertex data. If it has to do some processing (turn QUADS into TRIANGLES, like it usually has to do) then it will not be optimal. The only way to see what is optimal for your driver is to measure. Find a opengl benchmark and see which vertex primitives are optimal for your driver.

Since you want to compare GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP and GL_TRIANGLES, most likely you will find the performance loss to be minimal in this case.